# Why does webpack seem to stop listening to rules via dynamic import?

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

I have a special case where I need to treat a JS file as an `asset/resource` rather than a JS module.

If I do `import workerSrc from "@externalpackage/worker.min.js";` with my webpack config, everything works perfect.

If I do the following, it comes back as a module as if there was no webpack rule. What am I missing here?

```
const workerSrc = await import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "external-package-worker" */ "@externalpackage/worker.min.js"
);
```

My config rule for this is set up like this:

```
{
  test: /externalpackage.+worker(\.min)?\.js$/i,
  type: "asset/resource"
}
```

Comment: I think (but I could be wrong) that it is not supposed to work in such a way. This is because dynamic import only adds a link element with preload attribute. Therefore, your only option is to use `fetch` with bundled js in advance.

Answer (score -1):

When dynamically importing a default export you need read the default property. Since default is a keyword in javascript you need to alias it to something else.

```
const { default: workserSrc } = await import(
```

More details here:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/ecmascript-modules-dynamic-import/#22-dynamic-import-of-default

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).